# How to do cases on a function between finite types?

Tags: lean

I'm just starting out with lean.

Say I want to prove something about functions between two finite types. For example

```
example (f : Bool -> Bool) : (∀ x : Bool, f (f (f x)) = f x) := sorry
```

since there are just a few possibilities for `f` ideally I'd want something like `cases x <;> cases f <;> rfl`, but I can't do `cases f`.

Currently, I don't know how to prove this at all, I'd think `cases`/`match` on `(f false)` and `(f true)` but lean doesn't seem to remember this information about the function once it goes into the case.

Comment: there's some versions of this proof (for lean 3) [here](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/217875-Is-there-code-for-X.3F/topic/Kaminski's.20Equation); I think when the theory of finite types is passed along to lean 4 this should be very simole indeed

Comment: (it may already be there! I don't know much about lean4...)

Comment: From that thread, it seems like the cleanest lean 3 proof is `by revert f; dec_trivial`. Maybe you can do something similar in lean 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof along your original lines (not `dec_trivial`), note we use the `h :`  syntax to name the case hypothesis:

```
example (f : Bool -> Bool) : (∀ x : Bool, f (f (f x)) = f x) := 
by
  intro x
  cases x <;>
  cases h : f true <;>
  cases h2 : f false <;>
  simp [h, h2]
```

Comment: thanks, is there a general way to split a function?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? To always do cases on the finitely many outputs for a finite type? In Lean 3 there is a `fin_cases` tactic which was quite useful for this, but it hasn't finished being ported yet.